# Add option for requesting permission in Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I need to make a call to a phone in my application. But I'm confusing how to do it correctly for Android and higher. As I understand I need to call *requestPermissions* and then in *onRequestPermissionsResult* work with the result. But I need to store callNumber somewhere between this to functions.

I am really not sure that save phone number in Activity is a good idea, but I have no other options. So I write this code:

```
  public void callDriver(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:+%s", phoneNumber)));
    //FIXME: we need to save driver for calling in callback
    phoneNumberForCall = phoneNumber; //potential problem
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                          new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                          TaxiApp.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
    } else {
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TaxiApp.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:+%s", phoneNumberForCall)));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_call_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

If we save phone in activity it could change while an async request is processed& I understand that it would not be done, but it's potentially is a problem.

How should I make this correctly?

**P.S.**
Number which we call could change. More than that there is a list (recycleView) with numbers. User can click on each number and function *callDriver* will be called.

I am afraid of this situation:

1. User click on number -> function *callDriver* executes
2. *callDriver* requesting permissions. 1st number stored.
3. User click on another phone number -> function *callDriver* executes request permissions and stored number changed. 2nd number stored.
4. Permission granted. Callback executed and we call to the second number.

That's why we will not call to the first driver. I don't think this situation could happens ever. (User should click too fast for this.) But it's better to know how to do this correctly.

Comment: You can use sharedpreferences for this purpose. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: If the contact number will be same always you can write it here but if it is going to change or there can be various numbers store them in shared preferences and use it from there.

Comment: Agree with @Mr.Rabbit Use sharedpreferences  and you can use it aywhere in your app.

Comment: Save it to sharedpreferences or save it here looks same for me. I don't want to store number at all. Just to transfer it from permission request to permission callback somehow.
But thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences for saving the phone number. Here's the code:

Saving the phone number:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext); 
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
ed.putString(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_FOR_CALL, phoneNumber);
// ed.commit() can also be used but it is synchronous while ed.apply() is asynchronous.
ed.apply();
```

Retrieving:

```
String phoneNumberForCall = prefs.getString(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_FOR_CALL, defaultValue);
```

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Save it to sharedpreferences or save it here looks same for me. I don't want to store number at all. Just to transfer it from permission request to permission callback somehow. But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is whatever numbers you will call if will save to your Call log and you can get the data form there. using cursor

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);

int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

 switch (dircode) {

case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
//write your code here 
break;

}

}
```

then close the cursor obj and you will get list of mobile numbers

Comment: Thank you. This is really interesting and useful way to do it. I don't know much about Cursors. But now I know what to read about.